# Parsing with Scanner findWithinHorizon issue

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner, binary-operators

in a project I'm working right now, I need to parse escape sequences with the Scanner class (using Java in Linux). To include, for instance, the two END keys in the keyboard, I initially wrote the following code:

```
if(sc.findWithinHorizon("(\\G\\e\\[4~)?",0).length() > 0 || sc.findWithinHorizon("(\\G\\eOF)?",0).length() > 0 ) {
  System.out.print("END"); //To see if it works
```

With that code, I don't get any output (the terminal just freezes). After seeing that, I separated the two condition in two different if's:

```
 if(sc.findWithinHorizon("(\\G\\e\\[4~)?",0).length() > 0) 
   System.out.print("END"); 
 else if(sc.findWithinHorizon("(\\G\\eOF)?",0).length() > 0 )
   System.out.print("END");
```

Then it works. Does anybody know why it doesn't work with the OR operator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to capture what findwithinhorizon parses into a String then do your comparisons. What you're doing in the first if statement is parsing sc twice. Once doing a comparison for something then the second time doing a different comparison on a different part of the text.

I doubt this is the behavior you wanted. when you set horizon to 0 it's going to look at what is the current position then increment the position by one, so your second call is looking at a different index. If you truly have reached the end of the file I would believe this would cause some odd behavior and explain why it hangs.